# "to gatecrash smth" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Even though Maxwell gatecrashed society events and made (30) he was photographed with powerful figures such as Russia’s President Gorbachev, he never felt embraced by society.

1. What is "gatecrashed society events" in other words?
2. What is  embraced by society?

Answer (score 2):

To "gatecrash" means to attend an event to which a person has not been invited.

To "be embraced by society" means to be made to feel welcome by that part of society widely esteemed.

It is not surprising that you found the sentence confusing: a person should hardly expect to be welcomed at an event to which that person has not been invited. Perhaps the broader context resolves what seems nonsensical.